# from VGG16 model to Mobilenet and into android studio

Tags: python, keras

so this is the image classifier that I got from follow this tutorial https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html the current model for this is VGG16 I would like to change it into mobile net and implement it into android studio

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 140
nb_validation_samples = 40
epochs = 50
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)

print(cm)

plt.show()
```

would changing

```
 from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Dense

    vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
    x = vgg.output
    x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(vgg.input, x)
    model.summary()
```

into a pretrained mobilenet model could i implement these codes into android studio by just simply changing the .py file into .pb file and importing it into android studio?

Comment: You are asking at least 2 separate questions here and none of them is well defined: 1) how to change the backbone network and 2) how to migrate this model to android. Make your effort and then return with a specific question

Comment: You can basically change it easily to any model your keras version support by changing the import statement yes if that's what you are asking. If MobileNet can be found in your import yes.

Comment: hiya yeah i can change the model into mobilenet dense net and other types of model but idk how to i know that getting VGG16 and VGG19 is as simple as changing 16 to 19 in the codes but how do I do it for other models

Comment: I haven't done it before so it might be not the best way, but basically you should save your trained model to some `.h5` file and load it on your android with tensorflow or with other library. But if you want to train it on mobile then you should probably access to android's python and do some magic, it is very bad idea to train models on mobile so I won't recommend it.

Comment: aight lemme try it